# Maximum request length exceeded File upload asp.net

Tags: asp.net, maxrequestlength

I am getting error for Maximum request length exceeded.

I have set following line in my web.config file. still I am getting the same error.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1350000" enableVersionHeader="false" maxQueryStringLength="113584" executionTimeout="11600"/>
```

Can anyone please suggest me what else changes to be done in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

IIS7(and later version) has a built-in request scanning which imposes an upload file cap which defaults to 30MB. To increase it, you also need to add the lines below:

```
<system.webServer>

   <security>

      <requestFiltering>

         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="3000000000" />

      </requestFiltering>

   </security>

</system.webServer>
```

Used From : http://www.smarterasp.net/support/kb/a1544/how-to-resolve-maximum-request-length-exceeded.aspx